# Prevent Google Chrome Content Scripts from interfering with webpage DOM CSS definitions

Tags: css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extensions which injects a decent amount of JavaScript, CSS, and HTML into the page DOM for the current webpage tab.  It it does so to show a Modal window with my extensions functionality in that modal.

I cannot use the `background` or `popup` scripts to do what I need to do so I have to use a `content` script which injects into the actual page DOM.

My issue so far is I have to be super careful with CSS class names and JS as well as I have discovered if the page has a CSS class matching the name of any of my extensions CSS, my extensions ends up over-riding the pages CSS!

I have seen that some other extensions that have to do a lot of HTML, CSS, JS into the content end up injecting into there own `Iframe` in the page which helps prevent this name collision.

Is using an Iframe the standard best practice in this case?

One of the features in my extensions is to do full-page screeenshots which require my `contnet.js` script to send a message to my `background.js` script which is responsibble for calling the CHrome API and taking the screenshot of the current scroll position in the pages viewport.

- user clicks button in DOM modal windows
- content.js sends message to background.js with the coordinates of the viewport.
- background.js takes the screenshot with those coordinates.   THen sends a message back to content.js.
- content.js then scrolls down the page to the next area of the viewport for the next screenshot and then sends those new coordinates back to background.js.
- this cycle continues until a shot of the whole page is made and stiched together and then sends back the URL of the new image to content.js when done.

Because both the Chrome API needs to sends messages back and forth between my content.js and background.js and then also if there is an iframe the iframe has to send messages back and forth with the page and the iframe.

Because of this I am not sure if I could use an iframe or not even?

Also if I did use an iframe, it would not load the content from a remote server but instead would be loaded into the page as html.

So is there a best practice for doing this?

Comment: _“My issue so far is I have to be super careful with CSS class names ”_ – Prefix all your class names with something cryptic, or give the outermost element of your content an id (something cryptic as well, if you want to avoid collisions), and then prefix every one of your selectors with that id value …

Answer (score 0):

1. **Use inline styles instead**

   You can wrap your css in content.js then apply it to your target elements, it won't interfer the original design of the webpage
2. **Use [Shadow DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/)**

   It provides encapsulation for js/css and makes it easy to ensure your components separate from the DOM of the main document.